# "IS NULL" not working

Tags: mysql

So I've been looking around here and can't really figure out why this isn't working and would like to know if it is my syntax or just a problem with MySQL workbench. I'm pulling information from multiple tables but I can't get "is null" to work. "is not null" works just fine and a "SELECT * from orders where employee_id is null" works.

```
select orders.order_id, orders.order_date, orders.shipped_date, 
customer_last_name, employees.employee_id
from customers
join orders on
customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
join employees on
orders.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where orders.employee_id is null;
```

like i mentioned, in the above, "is not null" works correctly so "is null" should work fine too correct? There IS actually null data by the way.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?  Is it giving you an error message?  (If so, what's the error?)  Is it just giving you an empty set?  (If so, can you provide us an example of the table data.)

Comment: Your join clause and where clause will guarantee 0 rows together.

Comment: The rows with `orders.employee_id IS NULL` are filtered by the ON clause. Maybe you need a LEFT JOIN. You should post sample data and expected result.

Comment: When you remove the `WHERE ...` part from your query above, do you get rows where the `orders.employee_id` field is NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost immediately after I asked this question I figured it out. I joined a table that I didn't need and as a result, the table was excluding the null data since it was matching what I needed to query. I'll post the correct code and leave it up in case someone else runs in to a similar issue

```
select orders.order_id, orders.order_date, orders.shipped_date, 
customer_last_name
from customers
join orders on
customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
where orders.employee_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you be comparing 2 null values ??

```
join employees on orders.employee_id = employees.employee_id
where 
   orders.employee_id is null;
```

`orders.employee_id = employees.employee_id` for null is not a correct clause I suppose. It would be excluding `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your join. Try this or use a left join operation:

```sql
select orders.order_id, orders.order_date, orders.shipped_date, 
customer_last_name, employees.employee_id
from customers, orders, employees
where customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
and employees.employee_id is null 
and orders.employee_id is null;
```

Check your plans:
[image]